# Running on Device

Tags: xcode, device

On Xcode 4.2, I am trying to run my app on my iTouch (jailbroken on 4.2). The build succeeds however it ends automatically right after it succeeds without ever showing up on my device. I have already wen threw the prerequisites to run apps on my idevice without a dev account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devices left behind at 4.2.1 (armv6) are no longer supported in Xcode templates by default. There are a few hoops to jump through. [This answer from MattyG sums it up nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788578/927947).

Comment: @MattyG, Glad to hear it, since it was the correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have an Apple Developer Account? You have to register for it and get the provisioning profile for development.

Pay the US$99 .