# iOS 4.2.1 not supported in xCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4.2

I have updated my iPhone's OS to iOS version 4.2.1. After updating the iOS, the device is visible both in the organizer and in the xCode, if I connect. When I build and run an application in the device, the build gets succeeded and says completed running in the device. But, the application will not run in device. I am using xCode version 4.2. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292286/xcode-4-says-finished-running-my-app-on-the-targeted-device-nothing-happe

Comment: maybe you should close (or delete) this now answered question then?