# CGPoint giving the same value for x and y?

Tags: cgpoint

This is a strange bug I'm experiencing when testing on an old iPod. I'm trying to get location values on touchesMoved, but the y always outputs value equal to x. If I log using NSStringFromCGPoint, then I get the correct output. How come accessing x and y separately is not working?

```
CGPoint location = [singleTouch locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"Location using NSStringFromCGPoint %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location)); // output: {27, 136}
NSLog(@"Location using x and y %f %f",location.x, location.y); // output: 27, 27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem didn't haven't anything to do with CGPoint but rather with the plist parameters.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292286/xcode-4-says-finished-running-my-app-on-the-targeted-device-nothing-happe) solved my issue.

Comment: Correction. That solved only part of the issue. Be sure to also check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304716/xcode-4-2-armv6-release-bugs