# Xcode 4.2 + armv6 + release = bugs?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, release, armv6

I'm not really sure where my problem is but the scenario is as follows. I have a universal app set to a deployment target of 3.2 and Base SDK iOS 5.0. The project was created in Xcode 4.2.

I have set my Architectures to include both armv6 and armv7 for "Debug" and "Release"

"Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No"

While developing my app, I encountered a strange bug where my x and y values would not output correctly on older devices (y would always equal to x).

Once I removed "Required device capabilities" from my "Info.plist" the issue had gone away.

However, it appears that when I actually Archive my app for distribution, the issue is still there! How can this be explained? What else can I check?

Comment: In **Once I removed "Required device capabilities" from my "Info.plist"** you mean you removed armv7? Could you really test your app on armv6 devices before removing required device capabilities?

Comment: I don't know but the app started working on my old iPod once I did that.

Comment: Ok. This is what I expected. But I still don't understand the chronology of events. How can this **I encountered a strange bug where my x and y values would not output correctly on older devices** happen before you remove device capabilies? You can not test on old devices.

Comment: Oh right. I couldn't run the app directly from XCode. But there's a workaround via iPhone Configuration Utility. That let me install the app, so I saw the bug.

Comment: Ok :) and how do you test the app on old devices after archiving it?

Comment: Forget about my previous comment. Does the solution I posted work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was rightly pointed out by @sch. Here are the exact steps:

- Go to "Build Settings"
- Scroll down to "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language"
- Find "Other C Flags", select "Release" row
- Double-click on the cell in the second column from the right
- Click on "+" and write "-mno-thumb"

Comment: Eventually I'll be able to but the system puts in a delay for this kind of scenario. I have to wait a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7723824/1207152) to a previous question. In the comments, someone suggests a solution.

> Disabling build for Thumb on armv6 prevents these kinds of errors.