# Can't run my app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to run my app on my iphone for testing. I just got a new provisioning profile (it had expired about a month ago) i went through all the steps on [the assistant](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) and when I tried to run the app on the device from Xcode it builds it then claims to run it and says its finished running but it does nothing on the iphone not even install the app.

The only strange thing i found is that on the list of devices to deploy the app on on the top left on Xcode there are 2 instances of my iPhone even though in the organizer there is only one they both seem to be the same as when I changed the name of the iPhone they both changed as well. I have tried running on both of them and the same outcome explained above.

Any idea of what I could do?

EDIT: I'm running iOS 4.2.1 on n iPhone 3G

Comment: Try turning of xcode and turning it back on again. Seriously this works for more than half the issues I've encountered with the new xcode.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work I also turned the iPhone off and on again

Comment: I tend to agree. 1) reboot everything. 2) If still crashing, problem is somewhere in code. Add breakpoints and you will eventually find the problem.

Comment: It's not crashing. It compiles fine with no errors, says Finished running app on iPhone. There isn't even an icon on the iPhone and nothing at all happens on the iPhone when I run it. The app still runs on the Simulator just fine.

Comment: Go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292286/xcode-4-says-finished-running-my-app-on-the-targeted-device-nothing-happe

Comment: I haven't tried any of the stuff in this other question yet but it looks like it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the architecture from Standard (armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) to armv6 and armv7.
You can do this in Xcode - project - build settings - architectures (click on the drop down menu and the click other and the click on the plus sign) add armv6 and again click on the add sign and add armv7. Now build and run.
This worked for me.