# Apps made with new XCode won't run on iPod 2g

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I recently upgraded to the latest version of XCode, but apps made with this new version aren't running on my old iPod. I have the target version set to 4.0, when the iPod is 4.2.1. When I press the run button it goes through the normal building process, says "Running on iPod" then says "Finished running on iPod". But it doesn't run and the app isn't added to the screen. But if I try to run a project made on and older version of XCode it works.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work on newer devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `armv6` to the list of valid architectures. Go to your target settings, go to "build settings", search for "valid" to find "Valid Architectures", and change it to have two values, `armv6` and `armv7`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I remember checking that, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: here's a post that goes through the settings step by step http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292286/xcode-4-says-finished-running-my-app-on-the-targeted-device-nothing-happe