# changed product name in build settings, now app won't launch in simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6, ios-simulator

I wanted a different title to be displayed in the sub-title under my iPad app's icon and changed the `Product Name` for my app under `Build Settings`.

This worked but has had a strange side effect. Whilst the app continued to work perfectly on a connected iPad, on the emulator it now behaves in a similar way to that described in [this question].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292286/xcode-4-says-finished-running-my-app-on-the-targeted-device-nothing-happe)

Namely, it says it has `finished running <my app> on iPad 6.0 Simulator`

I tried changing the Product Name back but the problem persists. 
I also tried some of the suggestions on the other question (e.g. removing `armv7` frfom `Required Device Capabilities`) but nothing worked.

This isn't a showstopper at the moment as I have a real iPad to test on but I'd still like to understand what is going on, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like time for a reboot of the Mac. Restarting Xcode might suffice. One other thing to try is to delete the app from the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this on iPhone simulator 6. Many a times, when you click "Run" again - it runs without problem.

However if that doesn't work, you may try one of the following:

- Project->Command+Alt+Shift+K - a choice will appear saying something like clean folders. Do it.
- In organizer, go to derived data folder (finder) using tiny arrow just at the right of your project. Try deleting your project from finder. If it doesnt delete at once, try it often.
- Try resetting iPhone or iPad simulator.
- Exit XCode and reopen project. Do the same with iPhone / iPad simulator.

If you are wondering why this is happening, no one really knows! It's just some flags gone bad, restored once you re-do everything for it to work, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching off the Debugger?
So Edit Schemes -> Debugger -> None

Also restarting the Simulator and Xcode and cleaning the project may help

Answer (score 1):

Use another way: click on the azure icon of your project, keep the trackpad pressed until you see it allows to edit the name. Choose the name that you want, then a sheet like this will appear:

[image]

Click "rename" and you're done with it.